# Replace search prmNames

Tags: jqgrid

Looking at documentation I didn't find any way to change prmNames of search, is that possible?
I want to replace "searchField", "searchString", "searchOper".
I tried here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching and here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options but couldn't find any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sField`, `sOper` and `sValue` parameters of (the parameter `sFilter` can be used in case of advanced searching) to change the default values of the values by changing the `$.jgrid.search`. For example

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {sField: 'field', sOper: 'oper', sValue: 'value'});
```